# Integrating External Data into Blockchain: Can Validators Fetch and Incorporate API-sourced Data?

Tags: polkadot, api, runtime-api

Is it feasible for validators to retrieve information from external APIs, particularly news data, and seamlessly incorporate it into the blockchain?